# weak wifi signal kubuntu 16.04 Acer F15 with Qualcomm atheros

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, wireless, atheros

I am a real beginner. Since installing, wifi signals have been weak, never above 60% unless within 20cm of the signal source. Unfortunately I have not run this laptop with Windows or another operating system, so I am trying to determine whether this is a hardware or software problem. Here are what I hope are relevant console outputs:

```
stefan@stefan-Aspire-F5-573T:~$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] Mot de passe de stefan : 
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 31
   serial: 94:e9:79:de:0e:6b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.8.0-49-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 ip=10.0.9.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:131 memory:b1000000-b11fffff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
   logical name: enp3s0f1
   version: 12
   serial: a8:1e:84:0a:76:58
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:128 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1204000-b1204fff memory:b1200000-b1203fff


stefan@stefan-Aspire-F5-573T:~$ modinfo ath10k_pci
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-49-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless     /ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac WLAN   PCIe/AHB devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     8DB6E266EF9D63EC5C2B007
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000050sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000042sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000046sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000056sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000040sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000041sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000003Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        ath10k_core
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-49-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)
```

and finally

```
stefan@stefan-Aspire-F5-573T:~$ lspci -nnk|grep -iA2 net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31)
        Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:08a6]
        Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
--
03:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:108f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Is there anything I can try before opening the laptop to try and see if the antenna is connected properly?